# Android studio different timepicker

Tags: android, android-layout, datetime

How can I get this timpicker

[image]

Instead of this one?

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<TimePicker 
    android:id="@+id/timepicker_arbetstid"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: it depends on android version. In Lollipop devices you will get time picker as your second image and in pre-lollipop devices you will get it as your first image

Comment: Thank you, it solved my problem

Comment: how this comment solved your problem? your are not asking why you have the particular picker, but how you can get the first picker

Comment: Because now I can explain to the boss why I get it. However, I still need to change appearance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can try

`android:calendarViewShown="false"`

and

```
android:timePickerMode="spinner"
```

in the datepicker xml.

Comment: android:timePickerMode="spinner" did it for me

Answer (score 0):

For backwards compatibility, you may use this library to support material design time picker:

https://github.com/code-troopers/android-betterpickers